# Android, UI Element in custom View

Tags: android, android-view, ondraw

I'm getting used to creating custom views in android. One thing i wish todo is to include existing UI elements such as `EditText`, or `Switch` in my custom view.

I have previously developed with Cocoa (iOS), and was able to instantiate native elements within my custom view.

At `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` of my view, i have:

```
edit = new EditText(getContext());

edit.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = edit.getDrawingCache();

canvas.drawBitmap(b, 10, 10, paintDoodle);
```

When i execute, the app crashes before being shown. Am i going about this incorrectly, or is incorporation of native elements not possible in java?

Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:739)
            at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:91)
```

Comment: Can you post your LogCat please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very very possible to incorporate native elements, I do it daily, but you're doing it very wrongly. You don't directly draw them, you only directly draw if you're really doing a custom drawing, if you want an existing view inside your CustomView, you add that view to your CustomView.

Also, do never never never never never allocate `new` objects inside your `onDraw` method.

I'll show a quick example on what I consider to be the cleanest way.

```
public class MyCustomWidget extends LinearLayout {

  // put all the default constructors and make them call `init`

  private void init() {
      setOrientation(VERTICAL);
      LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_widget, this, true);
      // now all the elements from `R.layout.custom_widget` is inside this `MyCustomWidget`

     // you can find all of them with `findViewById(int)`
     e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
     title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

     // then you can configure what u need on those elements
     e.addTextChangedListener(this);
     title.setText(...some value);
  }
  EditText e;
  TextView title;

}
```

of course from this you can extrapolate to more sophisticated stuff, for example you have a `User` object and your `MyCustomWidget` is in an adapter you add a method:

```
public void setUser(User user) {
    title.setText(user.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is incorporation of native elements not possible in java?

No, it is possible.

This is how you can create an EditText programmatically for example:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

EditText editText= new EditText(this);
editText.setLayoutParams(params);
layout.addView(editText);
```

If you post the code of your custom view, I might be able to help you more.